# Java/IntelliJ/maven: so I made a change in a package and my other package can't see the updates?

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

might be best explain with an example:

- I have 2 maven projects (projectA and projectB)
- In projectB classes, I can use any of projectA public functions/features.
- I created a new function (let's call it functionX) inside of one of projectA's classes.
- I've build projectA already and I can see the new build inside $HOME\.m2\repository\whatever
- I want to use functionX in projectB but it's not auto-showing. But I can see other public functions of the class.
- Building the project from within IntelliJ results in an error (because I'm using a function it cannot identify).
- Building the same project in terminal and using "mvn clean install" does not produce an error.
- I tried "Reload all Maven projects" multiple times.
- I've closed and reopen IntelliJ multiple times.
- I'm using version 2022.2.3 CE.

Any ideas on how to fix/force a refresh? Thanks

---

sample snippet of my pom.xml in projectB

```
<projectA.version>(0.0,)</projectA.version>
..
..
..
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.myhost.projectA</groupId>
    <artifactId>projectA.core</artifactId>
    <version>${projectA.version}</version>    
</dependency>
```

Comment: Move your project to vscode, has better management of dependencies.

Comment: @PepeNO can I debug my code from within VSCode? Thanks

Comment: Of course, step by step and step over. Even visual studio is  more powerful.

Comment: I'm already using VSCode for other things (bash scripts). I might try if it works better for me. Thanks a lot for the suggestion! @PepeNO

Comment: Try IDE main menu `File | Invalidate Caches | Invalidate and Restart` to see if it helps. If still not, you may report this issue in IDEA issue tracker: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA